# How to debug memory corruption on Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory, heap-corruption

I am faced with a very smart memory corruption in my C application.

Corruption occures on high load.

So I tried purify, valgrind, mprotected and also I tried to write my own simple protection mechanism.

**Purify** / **Valgrind** - doesn't help because it reduces performance of my application and problem was not reproduced.

**mprotected** usage just move corruption to other memory location. (because it required to align memory to page size).

My simple protection mechanism doesn't work because it also reduces a performance.

How I can debug my application without performance degradation?

Comment: I'd be surprised if Valgrind wouldn't find it....

Comment: `Corruption occures on hight load.` How do you know? Also: monitor the process's VSIZ+RSS. Could be that you are just leaking memory.

Comment: How does the memory corruption manifest itself? Is your application single-threaded or multi-threaded? Is your hardware stable under stress tests?

Answer (score 0):

If you have 64 bit you can use a custom `malloc()` that always does `mmap()` and a custom `free()` that does `munmap()` and another `mmap()` on the same memory. Protect this stuff with a mutex to avoid a deadly race condition. This changes the behavior to fault on the first access to freed memory.

If it doesn't find it, adjust the custom `malloc()` to move the allocated buffer as high as possible in the mmapped area.

Note you can't do this in 32 bits because this burns address space like crazy.

Answer (score 0):

> Purify / Valgrind - doesn't help because it reduces performance of my application and problem was not reproduced.

While reading that, I believe you have not only a memory corruption but also one or more race conditions.

So I would give you the hind to first run with [helgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/hg-manual.html) to find the race conditions. But helgrind is not aware of memory ordering if you use `std::atomic`. In this case it reports false positives and is more or less unusable. For that situation I don't know any tool which checks for memory ordering, which is a big problem in the moment.

> How can I debug my application without performance degradation?

The question is: Why your failure depends on performance? Do you have I/O in parallel or running multiple tasks/threads? If so, reduce the speed of that tasks or threads or the I/O also, maybe you can force the error to raise.

Hints for slow down other threads/tasks:
On linux you can bind a thread/task to a cpu/core and you hopefully can consume more power on that single core by adding multiple "stopper" tasks also on that core. [taskset](https://linux.die.net/man/1/taskset). You may also compile special parts of your code with `-O0` or other hacks.

I know it is quite a nightmare to find bugs which are gone if you have debugging tools in place. But we can not really help, as we have nothing to take a look on... so it is a bit reading the crystal ball!

Comment: This isn't C++ -- there is no `std::atomic`.

Comment: @JL2210: I have no idea why I saw this question as it was from 5 years ago. Maybe it is now with c++ :-) And the problem is generic for c++ and c. Anyone who find that much to late answer useful may also find the hint to atomic useful. But yes, c has no atomics :-)

Comment: Joshua (one of the other answerers) bumped it to "Active" by answering it.

Comment: This has never been tagged [c++], though.

Answer (score 0):

use sanitizer:

add `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=thread` on your compilation flags and it will likely point you the defects.

You may also add `-O0` for removing optimization (better backtraces) and `-g` to keep symbols/debug info in your binary.